# handle user after Oauth2 redirect

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, jwt, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I create an application that client (vue) runs on localhost:3000 and server (express) on localhost: 8080.

I use passport-google-oauth20 strategy to log in using google and only JWT token.
My Question is: 
**How do I redirect to a client in a callback strategy so that the receives information about the logged-in user on client side?** I'm using in passport jwt, which i send on local-login strategy and there everything works.
At the moment, it looks like this to me:

```
this.router.get('/v1/auth/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['email', 'profile']})
); 

this.router.get('/v1/auth/google/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), (req, res) => {

        // let token = sign(req.user);
        res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000`);

        // how to redirect to the CLIENT, 
        // who will receive data about the logged-in user?
        // how get user data, catch this situation?
});
```

Comment: probably the only solution is to pass the value in a cookie